# Select and Group by together

Tags: sql, group-by, db2

I have my query like this:

```
Select 
  a.abc,
  a.cde,
  a.efg,
  a.agh,
  c.dummy
  p.test
  max(b.this)
  sum(b.sugar)
  sum(b.bucket)
  sum(b.something)
```

followed by some outer join and inner join. Now the problem is when in group by

```
group by 
  a.abc,
  a.cde,
  a.efg,
  a.agh,
  c.dummy,
  p.test
```

The query works fine. But if I remove any one of them from group by it gives:

```
SQLSTATE: 42803
```

Can anyone explain the cause of this error?

Comment: -1 For asking about a syntax error without specifying the RDBMS. This is wasting everybody's time.

Comment: A cursory web search indicates that it's DB2, but 42803 is a _state,_ not an error. Fixed that. If I'm wrong, Abhishek, please revert or improve.

Comment: yes you r right paxdiablo , i was mistaken and its DB2 .

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Generally, any column that isn't in the `group by` section can only be included in the `select` section if it has an aggregating function applied to it. Or, another way, any non-aggregated data in the `select` section must be grouped on.

Otherewise, *how* do you know what you want done with it. For example, if you group on `a.abc`, there can only be one thing that `a.abc` can be for that grouped row (since all other values of `a.abc` will come out in a *different* row). Here's a short example, with a table containing:

```
LastName  FirstName  Salary
--------  ---------  ------
Smith     John       123456
Smith     George     111111
Diablo    Pax        999999
```

With the query `select LastName, Salary from Employees group by LastName`, you would expect to see:

```
LastName  Salary
--------  ------
Smith     ??????
Diablo    999999
```

The salary for the Smiths is incalculable since you don't know what function to apply to it, which is what's causing that error. In other words, the DBMS doesn't know what to do with `123456` and `111111` to get a single value for the grouped row.

If you instead used `select LastName, sum(Salary) from Employees group by LastName` (or `max()` or `min()` or `ave()` or any other aggregating function), the DBMS would know what to do. For `sum()`, it will simply add them and give you `234567`.

In your query, the equivalent of trying to use `Salary` without an aggregating function is to change `sum(b.this)` to just `b.this` but not include it in the `group by` section. Or alternatively, remove one of the `group by` columns without changing it to an aggregation in the `select` section.

In both cases, you'll have one row that has *multiple* possible values for the column.

The [DB2 docs at publib](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v8/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.udb.doc/core/r0sttmsg.htm) for sqlstate 42803 describe your problem:

> A column reference in the SELECT or HAVING clause is invalid, because it is not a grouping column; or a column reference in the GROUP BY clause is invalid.

Comment: Another way of saying basically the same thing is, any column in the `select` list that is not aggregated must be included in the `group by` clause.

Comment: well ! i understood now ! in pictures .

Answer (score 3):

SQL will insist that any column in the SELECT section is either included in the GROUP BY section or has an aggregate function applied to it in the SELECT section.

[This article](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2007/07/20/but-why-must-that-column-be-contained-in-an-aggregate.aspx) gives a nice explanation of why this is the case. The article is sql server specific but the principle should be roughly similar for all RDBMS