# Getting accurate margins in one to many relationship DB2

Tags: db2, one-to-many

TLORDER_ALL is kind of summary table for a shipment. It will provide Total Payable to all carriers assigned to this shipment and Total Payable is recorded in INT_PAYABLE_AMT field.

On the other hand, ORDER_INTERLINER_ALL table will list Payable of each carrier assigned to a shipment from TLORDER_ALL Table. You basically have 1 to many relationship between TLORDER_ALL and ORDER_INTERLINER_ALL. The money paid to each carrier is recorded in AMOUNT field in ORDER_INTERLINER_ALL table. If after delivery, Accounting decides to adjust money payable to a carrier, adjusted payable to a carrier is recorded in ADJUSTED_AMOUNT in ORDER_INTERLINER_ALL table.If no adjustment, then ADJUSTED_AMOUNT=AMOUNT.

Note that each carrier assigned to a shipment may have different currency to be paid so that is the reason I use INT_PAYABLE_AMT *ADJUSTED_AMOUNT/AMOUNT to make conversion after adjustment by accounting because INT_PAYABLE_AMT is recorded in same currency as CHARGES (revenue) field in TLORDER_ALL table.

Long Store short, you may have a shipment with Revenue (CHARGES field) in USD and multiple carriers with CAD and / or USD currency. Total Payable (INT_PAYABLE_AMT) is recorded in same currency (USD) as Revenue (CHARGES) field after conversion. On the top of that, your revised payable to carriers (lets call it INT_PAYABLE_ADJUST_AMT) might be different from INT_PAYABLE_AMT.

**This is my Summary Query:**

```
`SELECT 
T.CUSTOMER,
T.CALLNAME,
COUNT(T.BILL_NUMBER) LOADS,
SUM(T.CHARGES+T.XCHARGES)TOTAL_REVENUE,
(SUM(T.CHARGES+T.XCHARGES)-SUM(T.INT_PAYABLE_AMT) *SUM(O.ADJUSTED_AMOUNT) /SUM(O.AMOUNT)) MARGIN
FROM TLORDER_ALL T
INNER JOIN ORDER_INTERLINER_ALL O ON O.DETAIL_LINE_ID=T.DETAIL_LINE_ID
WHERE T.INT_PAYABLE_AMT<>0
AND T.CHARGES+T.XCHARGES<>0
AND T.CUSTOMER='117990'
AND O.INTERFACE_STATUS='I'
AND O.AMOUNT<>0
GROUP BY T.CUSTOMER,T.CALLNAME`
```

[This is output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dWlnn.png)

**This is my Details Query**

```
SELECT 
T.DETAIL_LINE_ID,
T.BILL_NUMBER,
T.CUSTOMER,
T.CALLNAME,
(T.CHARGES+T.XCHARGES)TOTAL_REVENUE,
(T.CHARGES+T.XCHARGES-T.INT_PAYABLE_AMT *O.ADJUSTED_AMOUNT /O.AMOUNT) MARGIN,
T.INT_PAYABLE_AMT,
O.ADJUSTED_AMOUNT,
O.AMOUNT,
O.INTERFACE_STATUS
FROM TLORDER_ALL T
INNER JOIN ORDER_INTERLINER_ALL O ON O.DETAIL_LINE_ID=T.DETAIL_LINE_ID
WHERE T.INT_PAYABLE_AMT<>0
AND T.CHARGES+T.XCHARGES<>0
AND YEAR(T.DELIVER_BY)= YEAR(CURRENT DATE) 
AND MONTH(T.DELIVER_BY)=MONTH(CURRENT DATE)-1
AND T.CUSTOMER='117990'
AND O.INTERFACE_STATUS='I'
AND O.AMOUNT<>0
```

[This is the output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/alnb9.png)

My question is how I can eliminate multiple entries of same shipment because shipment has multiple carriers and to be able to get accurate final margin in Summary and Details output?

If we look back to Details image, I would like to get 5 records not 14 and to sum all carrier payables, converting it using INT_PAYABLE_AMT *ADJUSTED_AMOUNT/AMOUNT and subtracting from TOTAL_REVENUE for each line of those 5 records. Apply same logic to get accurate results in Summary output as well.

Thank you.

Comment: Your formatting makes the question hard to read, but the error message you are getting seems clear.  You cannot use `SUM` this way without a `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Subqueries written this way tend to execute per-line, taking a performance hit (although this might not be very large, if you only query for a single account).  Your query currently has a problem - if there's more than one `interface_status` line per detail line, it will discard one 'randomly' and silently, almost certainly not what you want.  You're rounding to two different decimal places.  Some sample data would be helpful to know how to better structure this query.

Comment: Hi, there not exist "o" table" and group by  clause for perform a sum agregate... Your sql syntax is wrong

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8121305/select-and-group-by-together

Comment: I reformatted question to give more details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok your summary is correct make that the CTE and then manipulate it step by step
(note I'm leaving all the rows in the first CTE -- this makes it easy to debug, comment out everything after and add in a select verify the values after each step):

```
WITH Detail AS
(
  SELECT 
    T.DETAIL_LINE_ID,
    T.BILL_NUMBER,
    T.CUSTOMER,
    T.CALLNAME,
    (T.CHARGES+T.XCHARGES)TOTAL_REVENUE,
    (T.CHARGES+T.XCHARGES-T.INT_PAYABLE_AMT *O.ADJUSTED_AMOUNT /O.AMOUNT)  MARGIN,
    T.INT_PAYABLE_AMT,
    O.ADJUSTED_AMOUNT,
    O.AMOUNT,
    O.INTERFACE_STATUS
  FROM TLORDER_ALL T
  INNER JOIN ORDER_INTERLINER_ALL O ON O.DETAIL_LINE_ID=T.DETAIL_LINE_ID
  WHERE T.INT_PAYABLE_AMT<>0
    AND T.CHARGES+T.XCHARGES<>0
    AND YEAR(T.DELIVER_BY)= YEAR(CURRENT DATE) 
    AND MONTH(T.DELIVER_BY)=MONTH(CURRENT DATE)-1
    AND T.CUSTOMER='117990'
    AND O.INTERFACE_STATUS='I'
    AND O.AMOUNT<>0
), C_COMBINE AS
(
  -- Here we combine the amounts for each leg
  SELECT
    DETAIL_LINE_ID,
    CUSTOMER,
    -- Payable amt and customer are always the same, just pick one.
    MAX(INT_PAYABLE_AMT) AS INT_PAYABLE_AMT,
    SUM(ADJUSTED_AMOUNT) AS SUM_ADJUSTED_AMOUNT,
    SUM(AMOUNT) AS SUM_AMOUNT
  FROM Detail
  GROUP BY DETAIL_LINE_ID, CUSTOMER
), ADJ_FOR_CURRENCY
(
  SELECT 
    DETAIL_LINE_ID,
    CUSTOMER,
    INT_PAYABLE_AMT * (SUM_ADJUSTED_AMOUNT/SUM_AMOUNT) AS AMOUNT
  FROM C_COMBINE
)
-- Now do what you want... roll up by customer?
SELECT 
  CUSTOMER,
  SUM(AMOUNT) AS TOTAL_FOR_CUSTOMER
GROUP BY CUSTOMER
```

Yes, this can all be written with less lines and less CTEs -- by combining steps into one.  But then it gets really hard to understand and and write.  Like this it is clear, you can add comments and test.  For example if the numbers are not coming out right you change the select to `SELECT * FROM C_COMBINE` and verify that step is working correctly.

Also, if you are using a decent optimizing server (and db2 is the best or in the top IMO - tho I do work for IBM so I might be biased) using a CTE in this way will often allow the compiler to make a faster execution plan in my experience.

Good Luck.

Comment: it gives error saying INT_PAYABLE_AMT is not in GROUP BY clause. Hogan, I also reformatted my question to give more details. Thank you.

Comment: @Zaur - I wrote a new answer based on your changes.  I hope it helps.  **I did not write the entire solution so don't expect that** Instead I pointed you in the right direction and gave you a couple of tools to use.